# Custom Filters class location in play framework

Tags: java, playframework-2.4

In an application developed using Play Framework 2.4, I need to use the Filters to add support for CORS.

The documentation does not mention a way to change the package in which the class is looked for. It simply says that the global package is a good location. After testing, it appeared that the global package is actually the only one fetched.

Is there, as for the Global class, a way to change the default location?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Play Documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaHttpFilters):

> If you want to have different filters in different environments, or would prefer not putting this class in the root package, you can configure where Play should find the class by setting play.http.filters in application.conf to the fully qualified class name of the class.

For example:

```
play.http.filters=com.example.MyFilters
```

Comment: How could I miss that... :/ Thanks!